# PySpark df.persist() corrupts dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
my_dataframe = sparkSession.createDataFrame( an_rdd, a_schema )
my_dataframe.show() # Works.
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.persist()
my_dataframe.show() # errors out.


ValueError: Length of object (69) does not match with length of fields (70)
```

This is pretty worrying.

Further:

```
my_dataframe = sparkSession.createDataFrame( an_rdd, a_schema )
my_dataframe.show() # Works.
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.persist()
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.unpersist()
my_dataframe.show() # Works.
```

This may be that Spark optimises out the persist/unpersist pair.

Persisting the dataframe is essential as the new set of operations create a dozen smaller dataframes for insertion to an RDBMS and we do not want to recalc the dataframe for each.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?  We have one column which is complex:

```
acolumn: array
 |-- element: struct
      |-- afield: string
      |-- asubfield: struct
           |-- afield: string
           |-- anarray: array
                |-- element: struct
                     |-- field
```

Is this causing pyspark to break the schema on persist()?

Comment: What does `my_dataframe.persist().show()` give you?

Comment: It errors out the same. :(

Comment: Please add the full error trace, including a minimum data set (and your `a_schema` definition) to reproduce this with.

Comment: I edited my question to show I was actually reassigning the dataframe through persist as I believe it's required.
I will see what I can do regards the stack trace and minimal data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question title and actual resolution do not match and hence it is misleading for a search.

Comment: That's fine.  Close away.  However, there is something iffy going on, as it does accept the schema and show() works, but the data does not conform to the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to a "skip rows in error" mechanic in a previous rdd mapping step.

If row is status error
return row
else
process row and add a column

So part of the data has 69 columns and parts had 70.  Hence the odd behaviour.

Comment: try scala instead of java. Not sure this is really a question.

Comment: I removed my rant about PySpark.